# jQuery animate method not stopping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my simple code for an animated slideshow. It supposed to make two things: 
 - first on 'mouseenter' event - it bounces "thumb" image
 - second - shows and bounces larger image of a thumbnail

```
$('img.thumb').mouseover(function (){
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500, function(){
        var src = 'images/screens/' + $(this).attr('id').substr(0,1) + '.jpg';
        $('.slideShow img').attr('src' ,src);
        $('.slideShow img').toggle('bounce').css('margin-top','2.5%');
        });
    });
$('img.thumb').mouseleave(function (){
        $('.slideShow img').fadeOut();
    });
```

The problem is that it works just perfect in Google Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it behaves crazy: thumb image keeps bouncing and larger image keeps appearing and disappearing forever.

What is the trick here?

Comment: try setTimeOut() function in mouseover

Comment: Which one is it, `mouseenter` (in your comment above the code) or `mouseover` (in the code)?

Comment: I think the problem is that it's animating the entire time that the mouse is OVER.  Instead, try using mouseenter so it only does that scenario once.

Comment: no. it does not make any difference. Even when I change to 'mouseenter' the problem still there

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your post, I think Jquery tooltip Widget is what you are looking for with custom animation:
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-animation

does that meet what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.thumb').mouseover(function (){
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500, function(){
        var src = 'images/screens/' + $(this).attr('id').substr(0,1) + '.jpg';
        $('.slideShow img').attr('src' ,src);
        $('.slideShow img').css('margin-top','2.5%');
        });
    });
$('img.thumb').mouseleave(function (){
        $('.slideShow img').fadeOut();
    });
```